# Get positive and negative review from steam api

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam, steam-web-api

I want to calculate % of positive reviews, but I can't found a data for it.
I'm using this endpoint to get information about game: "https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=" but there is only total number of reviews, also I know about this "https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/idhere?json=1" but numbers is not correct.

Comment: Most probably you'll have to scrape the shop page with headless chromium or something like that! The steam Web API just has some really basic features...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct numbers for the overhaul score of a given game can be obtained by forcing the language parameter to be 'all'.
https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/252950?json=1&language=all